# How to edit input with default value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, are there any other ways, rather than changing `value` to `defaultValue` to change the input value manually? (When using defaultValue My program doesn't work properly)

```
ChildComponent = React.memo(
  ({ name, index, onChange, onDelete
  }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={name} onChange={onChange(index, name)} />
        <button onClick = {() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
 function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(["First", "Second"]);
  const newName = React.useRef();

  const onNameChange = (index: number, newName: string) => (event: {
    target: { value: string };
  }) => {
    names[index] = event.target.value;
    setNames(names);
  };
  function onNameDelete(index: number) {
    const nameArr = [...names];
    nameArr.splice(index, 1);
    setNames(nameArr);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={index}
          name={name}
          index={index}
          onChange={onNameChange}
          onDelete={onNameDelete}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The concept is quite straightforward - state value should be initialized with default value when state value is created. And then it is changed by state setter in input change handler. Show us the code of parent component, how the `name` is initialized in state and how it is changed by onChange handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `onChange` input handler in your `ChildComponent`. You are not using passed value by user to input at all. You need to write it similarly to your `onDelete` handler (with use the new value, in my snippet stored in `event.target.value`):

```js
ChildComponent = React.memo(
  ({ name, index, onChange, onDelete
  }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={name} onChange={(event) => onChange(index, event.target.value)} />
        <button onClick = {() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Look also on the definition of the input change handler in [Html documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

EDIT:
Another issue is your handler in your parent controller:

```js
 const onNameChange = (index: number, newName: string) => (event: {
    target: { value: string };
  }) => {
    names[index] = event.target.value; //this is BAD, do not change your state value directly, moreover, the event is undefined here
    setNames(names);
  };
```

You need to update item in the array immutably (source [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array)):

```js
const onNameChange = (index: number, newName: string) => (event: {
  target: { value: string };
}) => {
  const newNames = names.map((item, itemIndex) => {
    if (itemIndex !== index) {
      // This isn't the item we care about - keep it as-is
      return item
    }

    // Otherwise, this is the one we want - return an updated value
    return newName;
  });
  setNames(newNames);
};
```